# Unable to include a class into another in IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4

I wish to create object of one class into another
I have 2 classes

1. MyviewControler
2. Checkout

I want to import Checkout into  MyviewController

```
#import "Checkout.h"

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
{
    Checkout *checkout;
}

@property (nonatomic) Checkout *checkout;

@end
```

It is giving me error "Unknown type name checkout"

Comment: Please include the contents of Checkout.h in your question, too.

Comment: Also, use `@property (nonatomic, retain)`.

Comment: At which line it gives you error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In MyViewController.h, before @interface add:

```
@class Checkout;
```

In MyViewController.m, add:

```
#import "Checkout.h"
```

Comment: See my comment to Mayur Joshi. Neither the forward declaration nor the extra import should make a difference here.

Comment: I forgot to mention removing #import on Checkout.h . Thought it was obvious.

Answer (score 4):

you probably have a dependency cycle. use a forward declaration, which tells the compiler there is a class with that name without needing to see its declaration:

```
@class Checkout; // << the forward declaration

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
{
    Checkout *checkout;
}

@property (nonatomic) Checkout *checkout;

@end

// MyViewController.m
...
#import "Checkout.h"
```

forward declarations are preferred in the majority of cases. the exception to this is when there is a  physical dependency (e.g. the superclass' declaration should precede the subclass'). forward declarations are good  because they significantly reduce the build times and the complexity of include graphs and dependency.

good luck

Answer (score 4):

If the error really is as you say:

```
Unknown type name checkout
```

(note the small 'c') then the problem is that you're using `checkout` as a type name instead of `Checkout` somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

import the file in MyViewController.m file too.

```
  //in .m file
  #import "Checkout.h"

  @class Checkout;   //this was missing
```

Also, give the property like this.

```
  @property(nonatomic, retain) Checkout* checkout
```

and synthesize it in .m file

Comment: Presumably, the `Checkout` class is declared in Checkout.h, so there's no reason for a forward declaration (`@class Checkout`) if that file is being imported. And if it's being imported into MyViewController.h, there should be no reason to import it into the .m file as well. Agree about the retain, but whether it's synthesized or not shouldn't matter with respect to the error at hand.